# Datatable filter - Excel filter functionality and and UI design

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, kendo-ui, filtering

I am new to jquery and am using datatable to create a table dynamically. I have been able to create a datatable and was able to add filter functionality [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/1pede2q3/) , but I havent been able to get the excel like filter functionality and UI design (like below examples) working in my code.

I found a few additional plugins which can provide similar feature but havent found a way to do it manually. Is there any way we can do it manually with out using additional plugins?

Working Examples:

[Example 1](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-with-excel-like-filter)

[Example 2](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Excel-like-Bootstrap-Table-Sorting-Filtering-Plugin/)

My Code:

```js
// Create search header
var new_row = $("<tr class='search-header'/>");
$('#example thead th').each(function(i) {
  var title = $(this).text();
  var new_th = $('<th style="' + $(this).attr('style') + '" />');
  $(new_th).append('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" data-index="' + i + '"/>');
  $(new_row).append(new_th);
});
$('#example thead').prepend(new_row);

// Init DataTable
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  "scrollX": true,
  "searching": true,
});

// Filter event handler
$(table.table().container()).on('keyup', 'thead input', function() {
  table
    .column($(this).data('index'))
    .search(this.value)
    .draw();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Extn.</th>
      <th>E-mail</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger</td>
      <td>Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>5421</td>
      <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett</td>
      <td>Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
      <td>8422</td>
      <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton</td>
      <td>Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
      <td>1562</td>
      <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric</td>
      <td>Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
      <td>6224</td>
      <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi</td>
      <td>Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
      <td>5407</td>
      <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle</td>
      <td>Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
      <td>4804</td>
      <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to use drop-down filters - like in [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select)?

Comment: yeah this is close but i was looking for more excel like functionality where I can directly have a filter option within the header similar to this - https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-with-excel-like-filter

Comment: Yes - that link is in your question already, and I did see it. So, what I think you are saying is: It's not just the _functionality_ that you want - it's also the _UI design_ features, too. Is that correct?

Comment: yeah that is correct. sorry for not making it clear in the question. I have updated it now. Thanks!

Comment: @andrewjames would you be able to help me on this or point me to the right direction on how/if this might be possible?

Comment: You're asking how to build a very specific piece of web UI: a clickable icon which shows/hides a select list next to the button. The two "example" links show ways of doing that, and I expect there are other libraries which also can do that. So, I would say: Go figure out that specific piece first, independently of DataTables - and then come back to see how to integrate that into the heading cells of a DataTable. As it stands, I think you are asking for quite a lot in this question. So, maybe break it down into smaller, separate pieces.

Comment: Make sense, thanks! Let me try this approach and see if I can figure this out.